# How to store xls file data to sqlite data base

Tags: android, sqlite, xls

I want to show xls file data to sq-lite data base,i don't have idea about that please help me,i have created xls file and also read it but don't now how to show that data to insert that data in sq-lite.In below code i have given the read xls file code

```
try
{
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/raav.xls"));                     
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs); 
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator(); 
while( rows.hasNext() )
{ HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) 
    rows.next(); 
System.out.println("\n"); 
Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
while( cells.hasNext() )
{
 HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next(); 
 if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType()) 
 System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+" " ); 
 else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType()) 
 System.out.print( cell.getStringCellValue()+" " ); 
 else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType()) 
 System.out.print( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+" " ); 
 else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType()) 
 System.out.print( "BLANK " );
 else 
 System.out.print("Unknown cell type"); } }}
 catch (Exception e) {
    }
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what you want. Do you want to directly store the XLS file or convert it to a table/s?

Comment: i want to store directly into sq-lite data base

Answer (score 0):

To store a binary file in a DB you can either use BLOB type and pass it a `byte[]` or use String and convert back and forth from Base64.